# Unable to read variables from Terraform variable file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my setup,

Terraform version - Terraform v0.12.17
OS - OSX 10.15.1

Use Case - define a provider file and access the variables defined in the vars file

Files
main.tf - where the code is

```
provider "aws" {

}

variable "AWS_REGION" {
    type = string
}

variable "AMIS" {
    type = map(string)
    default = {
        us-west-1 = "my ami"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "awsInstall" {
    ami = var.AMIS[var.AWS_REGION]
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

awsVars.tfvars - where the region is defined

```
AWS_REGION="eu-region-1"
```

Execution

$ terraform console

> > var.AWS_REGION
>
> Error: Result depends on values that cannot be determined until after "terraform apply".

What mistake I have done, I don't see any syntax but have issues in accessing the variables, any pointers would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Terraform does not automatically read a `.tfvars` file unless its filename ends with `.auto.tfvars`. Because of that, when you ran `terraform console` with no arguments Terraform did not know a value for variable `AWS_REGION`.

To keep your existing filename, you can pass this variables file explicitly on the command line like this:

```
terraform console -var-file="awsVars.tfvars"
```

Alternatively, you could rename the file to `awsVars.auto.tfvars` and then Terraform will read it by default as long as it's in the current working directory when you run Terraform.

There's more information on how you can set values for root module input variables in the Terraform documentation section [Assigning Values to Root Module Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables).

---

Note also that the usual naming convention for input variables and other Terraform-specific objects is to keep the names in lowercase and separate words with underscores. For example, it would be more conventional to name your variables `aws_region` and `amis`.

Furthermore, if your goal is to find an AMI for the *current* region (the one chosen by the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable, or in the provider configuration), you could use [the `aws_region` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/region.html) to allow Terraform to determine that automatically, so you don't have to set it as a variable at all:

```
variable "amis" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    us-west-1 = "my ami"
  }
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_instance" "awsInstall" {
  ami           = var.amis[data.aws_region.current.name]
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, renaming the file with "auto.tfvars" helped. I am new to Terraform, earlier project had used Ansible and I am trying to adopt terraform as a part of infra automation. I will read further on the links.